# Can legendary Pokemon evolve or undergo Mega Evolution?

Tags: pokemon

I have not seen any evolution of Legendary Pokémon yet. I'm not talking about [pseudo-legendary Pokémon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pseudo-legendary_Pok%C3%A9mon).

I did some more research and found that [Mewtwo can Mega Evolve](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mewtwo_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), but it is not a natural Legendary Pokémon, it is a man-made clone of Mew.

Comment: Are you looking for anime appearances or just the existence of a legendary that can mega evolve?

Comment: @TheGamer007 It is an anime site so basically I will look for anime appearances but the knowledge from any reliable source manga could be taken as reference for the future.

Comment: Is this even an anime question or game related?

Comment: This seems more of a game-related question rather than anime/manga.

Comment: @W.Are how it is game related? In pokemon anime, if the ultra beast can evolve then why not legendary pokemon, everything about them is unknown just like an ultra beast. It is one of the mysteries of pokemon just like their existance.

Comment: may be mega rayquza is the answer.https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rayquaza_(Pok%C3%A9mon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Gen VIII, there are only two Legendary Pokémon capable of evolving:

- Cosmog, which evolves into Cosmoem, and then into either Solgaleo or Lunala
- Meltan, which evolves into Melmetal

Both are shown doing this in the *Sun and Moon* anime: Cosmog while under Lillie's ownership, and Meltan while under Ash's ownership.

The following Legendary Pokémon (discounting Mewtwo) are capable of undergoing Mega Evolution and have been shown doing so in the anime:

- Latias and Latios (seen in the anime movie *[Hoopa and the Clash of Ages](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M18)*)
- Rayquaza (seen in the [Mega Evolution Specials](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/XYS02) and in *Hoopa and the Clash of Ages*)
- Diancie (seen in the anime movie *[Diancie and the Cocoon of Destruction](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M17)*)

Groudon and Kyogre are also capable of undergoing a process called Primal Reversion that is very similar to Mega Evolution but not quite the same. They are shown doing this in the Mega Evolution Specials, *Hoopa and the Clash of Ages*, and in *Pokémon Generations*.

Comment: Just to cover all grounds, Meltan can evolve into Melmetal. Meltan is a Mythical, which is a sub-category of legendary

Comment: Ah, forgot about Meltan, well-remembered.

Answer (score 1):

> "Legendary Pokémon" (伝説のポケモン, Densetsu no Pokémon) is a term of art.[...] In *most cases*, Legendary Pokémon are exceptionally powerful, difficult to catch, and **unable to evolve**, and no known Legendary Pokémon is capable of breeding.

source: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gameplay_of_Pok%C3%A9mon)

The few exceptions are **"Nebby"** in the 7th generation evolving to Solgaleo or Lunala, depend on the game version and there's also **Primal Evolution** of Kyogre and Groudon in OmegaRuby and AlphaSapphire which is a different term of Mega Evolution.

The reason for the Legendary Pokemon not evolving is pretty simple since evolution is a phenomenon to make Pokemon stronger than it was and as quoted from Wikipedia the legendary Pokemon in their normal state are powerful enough and not need to be evolved to get more strength.